# TeamCity building Git / GitHub pull requests

Tags: git, github, teamcity

We have a TeamCity 7.1 installation that builds all branches from a GitHub repository.

GitHub has a notification hook back to TeamCity to trigger a build on check-in. We also have TeamCity polling GitHub every 120 seconds to check for changes (in case the server was offline when a change was checked in).

Our normal development follows a common pattern:

1. Create a branch from master
2. Commit to that branch until finished with a feature
3. When finished, pull from master to merge any changes and push to remote
4. Submit a GitHub pull request to allow the admins to merge into master

Everything is working swimmingly (after much searching to get the correct configuration settings) however...

The above process triggers several builds on TeamCity and I'd like to know whether they're all necessary. Typically we'll end up with:

- A build for /refs/heads/*branch-name*
- A build for /refs/pull/*number*/head
- A build for /refs/pull/*number*/merge

Naturally the first build is the last check-in on the particular branch, and the second build is the pull request, but **what is the third build for?**

Comment: Typically this wouldn't be a problem but running our entire RoR test suite with integration tests is taking ~10 minutes, so we're not getting build-status feedback on the pull requests for up to 30 minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your builds seem redundant. The more thrifty way to organize TeamCity builds of feature-branches in git is as follows:

1. Organize continuous integration of your `refs/heads/master` branch. 120 seconds poll is quite reasonable here.
2. Organize nightly-builds for every `refs/heads/feature-name` branches. As of my experience, only a few of the feature-branches require 120-seconds polling.

TeamCity 7.1 has a very nice feature to autotrigger feature-branches, so step (2) can be setup in a couple of clicks with a branch mask like `refs/heads/feature-*`.

There is no meaning in building pull requests since they will be covered by master builds.

Comment: In relation to building pull requests, the new GitHub build status API allows us to show the build status for a pull request directly on GitHub, which is a massive timesaver. This shows up when we build the /pulls/1/head branch.

Comment: For those interested, one of the key settings that we changed was the branch spec as above (slightly modified), and **removed the trigger build on each check-in** option that was causing most of our headaches

Answer (score 13):

Third build is actually the most valuable — it's the result of pull request auto merge (merge that happens, when you press the button at github).

Comment: This also means that merging from master into the pull request branch is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer, in case someone still uses TeamCity

Since 2018, there is a native [Pull Request Build Feature](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/pull-requests.html). This is a better solution compared to using branch triggers & filters, since it creates a two-way link between the build and the corresponding PR *and* frees you from having to add any `refs/pull/...` to the VCS Branch Spec.

Still, if you insist on using `pull/*/merge`: note that this creates superfluous builds **in case** the "*Require linear history*" (=only allow Rebase & Squash merges from PRs) feature is enabled on the GH repo, since a PR in such case can only be merged once it is up-to-date with its base branch anyway.

Comment: 8 years later I'm glad that someone cares enough to respond with updated info! Kudos.